# Many problems booting / shuting down ubuntu 12.10

Tags: gnome, boot, touchpad

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 about a month ago, and since then it's been some kind of a nightmare! not listing all the issues I had to face, now I have this weird behaviour that really bugs me: when I turn on my pc (and if it properly boots after grub's menu), sometimes the synaptic touchpad does not work at all. I can login using the keyboard and then use the terminal to try to reboot or attempt to fix problems, but this results usually in the pc freezing at the "exit" screen, with strange lines of messages interfering with the coloured background. Every possible solution found to fix the touchpad won't be of any help.
Thus, with no touchpad and the pc stuck, all I can do is to brutally shut the pc down and restart: it usually takes from two to five times in a row of "brute-shut-downs_reboots" before getting the touchpad back working. And when it works, I can check all properties and log files related, but always everything appears to be fine.

I'd like to know which conditions could lead to such random behaviour and, if any, which actions to attempt in order to solve this annoying problem

ps
I'm running ubuntu 12.10 64bit with gnome3, linux kernel 3.5.0-21-generic. But these problems persist also in unity.  What I've noticed is that using kernel 3.5.0-18-generic the whole system just runs better, but it might be just a feeling!

Comment: I had a similar experience. After updating to kernel 3.5.0-21, ubuntu 12.10 wouldn't boot. Then I installed Ubuntu 12.04, but it was too buggy. Then I found Xubuntu 12.10, which is awesome! However, I'm scared to update to the new kernel now...

Comment: Do you use any privative drivers?

Comment: @Catbuntu I don't. Not for the touchpad, not even for the NVidia GPU (Optimus technology, but I had a tragic experience with bumblebee and drivers, so I'm just using `bbswitch`). No private drivers, just plain 12.10 with Gnome3, since Unity started,after a month and a couple of kernel updates, to overload CPUs and graphic dramatically slowed down.

Answer (score 0):

3.5.0-21 seems slow in general. I reverted to 3.5.0-19 and everything is fine again.
On boot, hold the right shift key down, go to the Advanced Setting menu and choose the previous kernel.

Comment: Well at the moment, I keep using 3.5.0-21 without problems. Only, I try to not power off the pc; i rather suspend, and except for some failure messages I get when I wake it, everything really runs nicely. Still if I reboot, it is likely to have that touchpad problem back.